# Which way is better to change specific item in array of objects in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react from some tutorial, but it's little bit old, so I'm trying to find new ways.  There is code:

```
const data = [
    { label: 'Going to lern react', important: true, like: false, id: 1 },
    { label: 'That is good', important: false, like: false, id: 2 },
    { label: 'I need a break', important: false, like: false, id: 3 },
]

const [posts, setPosts] = useState(data)
```

First option is what he did on video, but with few changes from me, because he was using this.setState

```
const onToggleImportant = (id) => {
    setPosts(() => {
        const index = posts.findIndex(elem => elem.id === id);

        const old = posts[index];
        const newItem = { ...old, important: !old.important };

        const newArr = [...posts.slice(0, index), newItem, ...posts.slice(index + 1)];

        return newArr;
    })
}
```

I don't like these slices tbh.
And there are my two options:

```
const onToggleImportant = (id) => {
    setPosts(posts.map(el => el.id === id ? { ...el, important: !el.important } : el));
}
```

or

```
const onToggleImportant = (id) => {
    setPosts(() => {
        const newPosts = posts.map(el => el.id === id ? { ...el, important: !el.important } : el);
        return newPosts;
    })
}
```

In last one I tried to avoid mutation, but not sure if it was necessary, because there are no error in console or from eslint.
So, which options is better and why? Or maybe there is another new way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [functional pattern](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b/#:%7E:text=React%20has%20popularized%20functional%20programming,web%20development%20ecosystem%20at%20large.) of `setState` which is the ideal way to go if your new state value depends on previous state.
But you are not using the previous state value. It is the first parameter to the callback inside `setState`:

```
const onToggleImportant = (id) => {
    setPosts((posts) => posts.map(el => el.id === id ? { ...el, important: !el.important } : el));
}
```

The above code (which uses your 2nd approach) also doesn't mutate the state, because you are using `spread` with el. Also, `map()` returns a new array, so your state is updated well.

Comment: Should I always use prevState even if it works without? I thought state posts already contains same data

Comment: It is better to use the `prevState` to avoid conflicting changes or possible closures